# First Time Using Regex

Tags: java, html, regex, string

So it's my first time using regex and I'm stuck at this one issue.

Here is the string:

```
<img src="//i.imgur.com/ptJ4U.jpg" />
```

I'm trying to use regex to make extract the image url.

This is what I'd like the output of the string to be:

```
i.imgur.com/ptJ4U.jpg
```

So basically I want to extract the url from the html code. What would be the regex pattern to do that?

Comment: This is a situation where using an HTML parser is a lot more reliable than a regular expression; there are a lot of traps that you can run into here, and the parsers already exist to do the work for you.

Comment: I agree with chrylis. Also, if you ever need to do regex again, try this: http://regexr.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=<img\ssrc="\/\/)[^"]*
```

You can try this.Use `search` mathod.
See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/21